# change the date format in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date column as dd-mm-yyyy. I would like to convert it to yyyy/mm/dd in bigquery.I have written the following query:
SELECT cast(format(Date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as string) as Date FROM t1.

The error is : Too many arguments to FORMAT for pattern "23/04/2020"; Expected 1; Got 2.

Can you please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to parse date from `dd-mm-yyyy` string and then format it as `yyyy/mm/dd` as in below

```
FORMAT_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', day))
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '15-01-2020' day UNION ALL
  SELECT '05-10-2019'
)
SELECT day, FORMAT_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', day)) AS formated_day
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row day         formated_day
1   15-01-2020  2020/01/15   
2   05-10-2019  2019/10/05
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  He said he had a date column- why would you need to parse it? Maybe I'm just reading too much into the prompt and the column is not actually of a date type.

Comment: somehow I am under impression that his column is of string type. I can be wrong though, but my answer had this assumption

Answer (score 1):

You want [`FORMAT_DATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date), not `FORMAT`.

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", DATE "2008-12-25");
```

The reason you're having trouble with `FORMAT` is that you gave it a format string that doesn't take any parameters.  Seeing this, the engine barfs-"I don't need any more parameters to render this string."

Comment: @ Frank, It gives me all "2008-12-25". i want corresponding date against Date column

Comment: Right, just use `SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", Date)`, or whatever your date column is called.  That example was to prove the concept.

Comment: @ Frank, My Date column is string. it shows an error. I have converted string to Date. It shows an error:  Invalid date: '23/04/2020'

Comment: It's pretty unclear what type your actual data is.  You might try @Mikhail's solution below.

Comment: @ Frank, my date is currently set as 23/04/2020 this format and it is string type. I want to get 2020-04-23 for all the rows in date column.